# Referencing resources in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

In our project we have some wpf dialogs and decided to move some of the commonly used styles to a separate assembly so that we could reuse them. The problem that we have now, is how to properly reference these resources in xaml? It should be noted that we are developing a plugin for a third party application and the key thing to keep in mind here is that our plugin assemblies are located in a different folder than the application itself.

We have tried using this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary 
            Source="pack://application:,,,/Wpf.CustomStyles;component/Styles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But it doesn't work. I would try to guess (I'm not an expert on this, so apologies if I'm way of track here), this doesn't work because it looks for a Wpf.CommonStyles.dll in the same folder as the .EXE file of the application, but as I've said, our plugin assemblies are installed in a different folder. So my question is, what the proper line for the Source attribute should be if I want the framework to look for Wpf.CommonStyles in the same folder where the "calling" assembly is located, rather than looking for them where the application .exe is located?

Comment: It should work like that as long as the `Build Action` of `Styles.xaml` is set to `Resource`. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970494.aspx#Resource_Files).

Answer (score 0):

As long as the DLL in question is copied upon build to the target folder (set `copy local` to `true` in the reference's properies), this should be no problem.

Litterature on the subject [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).